# issue in installing lxml in python 3.5

Tags: python-3.5

I have tried to install lxml by downloading "lxml-3.6.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl" file and installing it by giving command pip install lxml-3.6.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl on cmd but am getting error: lxml-3.6.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not supported wheel on this platform. what should I do to install?

Comment: Are you using a 32 or 64 bit version of python?

Comment: 32 bit version of python

Comment: And pip points to python3.5?

Comment: you mean about the path

Comment: I mean that you can have more than one version of pip